# Android : how to make sure AlarmManager are not crash first AlarmManager are haven't finish execute?

Tags: android

```
public class AlarmManagerClass extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
    public static boolean haveInternet(Context ctx) {

        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (info.isRoaming()) {
            // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to
            // disable internet while roaming, just return false
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


     @Override
     public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
     wl.acquire();

     // Put here YOUR code.
     Log.d(null,"Alarm !");
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

            Thread falador = new Thread() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     while (haveInternet(context)==false){
                         try {
                            sleep(60000);
                            if (haveInternet(context)==true){
                                PostSync(context);
                                                    return;
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }
                 }
          };
              falador.start
            Log.d(null,"Alarm Exit !");
     wl.release();
     }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerClass.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
 }

}
```

I have an AlarmManager that will `PostSync();` every 10 Minutes, where `PostSync` is the function to synchronize data to the server.

For example :
After 10 minutes the AlarmManager wakes up, and checks if there is a network connection or not. If there is no connection, it will check again by 60 second later.

So, whenever it doesn't have internet connection in 10 Minutes, the first AlarmManager's Task haven't finish executing, because it is waitng for an internet connection. The second AlarmManager wakes up and checks whether it `haveInternet` or not, if it doesn;t it will sleep for one minute, etc. So, this is the infinity circle....will this happen on this code?

**How to make sure if the first AlarmManager's Task are haven't finish execute, do not wake up the second AlarmManager?**

Comment: I don't get how you wait 60s if you don't have internet connection : your `falador ` thread is never run ?

Comment: @Pierre Rust Sorry, Some mistake

Comment: OK, but I still think it flaky, see my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `set` instead of `setRepeating` and schedule your next task only once your first task is actually finished. That way you will be sure you can never have two concurrent AlarmManager and, when you have an internet connection, your task is run every 10 minutes.

I think it would event be much simpler that way : you use `AlarmManager#set` with a 10 minutes delay. In the task you check if you have an internet connection :

- in that case, do your job and set the next alarm with `AlarmManager#set` with a 10 minutes delay
- otherwise, set the next alarm with `AlarmManager#set` with a 60 seconds delay

I think the current approach with a thread started by your alarm task is flaky, if you use AlarmManager, use it for both or your delay, 10 minutes and 60 seconds.

Comment: Great Job !, should use `set` instead of `setRepeating`, after a task done, only determine the next AlarmManager wakeup time

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise You can choose one more simple approch 
in onreceive method you can check if net available or not ??

i m saying that using broadcast receiver and alarm manager you call onreceive method of your AlarmManagerClass and perform sync operation right ? 
now when alarm trigger first task check internet 
1) if available then perform your sync operation and make alarm after 10min.

if yes --- then perform sync operation with server and Sleep Alarm For 10 minute = 60*10*1000

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerClass.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); and
```

2) now suppose no internet available then make alarm after 1min

else-- then perform no sync operation with server and  sleep for 1 minute 60*1*1000

```
  AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerClass.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60, pi);
```

and use only one alarm manager to handle your stuff

and i also suggest you if you want to perform sync operation then use service for background operation for smoother execution

suggest to refer these 
[Link 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
[Link 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#service_intentservices)

Comment: i dont understand what exactly u mean, u r meaning when if net available then sleep alarm for 10 minutes if not then have to cancel the first alarm and then reset the new alarm with 1 minute. right? is this method keep setting new alarm and canceling alarm, will cause the RAM low memory?

Comment: do you mean, u have to declare AlarmManager as class global variable, then setRepeating time depend on network available or not? right?